# Uncaught ReferenceError: fn is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a jQuery function, but it doesn't work. I get this error in the development console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: fn is not defined`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.Restrictions = function () {
    if($('#restriciton_cb').checked)
        {
            $('#RestrictionDiv').fadeIn('slow');
        }else{
            $('#RestrictionDiv').fadeOut('slow');
        }
    };
    $('#restriciton_cb').change(function(){
        fn.Restrictions;
    });
    fn.Restrictions;
});
```

Have you an idea?

Comment: Shouldn't `fn.Restrictions` be `$.fn.Restrictions`

Comment: Exactly, the error has disappeared but the function doesn't work on load and when I click on the checkbox.

Comment: To do that you need to execute the function. Update the code further to `$.fn.Restrictions()`

Comment: That's not the way you should create and use method extending jQuery prototype, see for examples: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: `.checked` at `$('#restriciton_cb').checked` return `undefined` error ?

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found an answer :

```
function valueChanged()
{
    if($('#restriciton_cb').is(":checked"))   
        $("#RestrictionDiv").show();
    else
        $("#RestrictionDiv").hide();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#restriciton_cb').change(function(){
        valueChanged();
    });
    valueChanged();
});
```